# Failure of Stone-Weierstrass theorem on infinite domain

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

On $\mathbb{R}$, the functions $\sin x$ and $e^x$ can not be uniformly approximated by polynomials.

*My intuition:* (1) If $P_n(x)$ is a sequence of functions converging uniformly to $\sin x$,  then for $\epsilon=1$, there is integer $N$ such that $|P_n(x)-\sin x|<1$ for all $n\ge N$. In particular, the graphs of $P_N(x), P_{N+1}(x),\cdots$ lie within level $[-2,2]$ because $|\sin x|\le 1$. However, polynomial $P_N(x)$ is unbounded i.e. for large $x$, $P_N(x)$ is large. Hence uniform approximation considered in beginning is not possible.

(2) For $e^x$, this function grows faster than any polynomial $p(x)$ for $x$ large; hence there is impossibility of uniform approximation on $\mathbb{R}$ by polynomials.

**Q.1** Are the solutions correct?

**Q.2** I didn't write clear proof for $e^x$ (my first statement in (2) is not rigorous one; its only roughly written justification; I couldn't formulate it properly mathematically); can one suggest some lemmas (only statements) which will give proof for $e^x$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically by definition, the sup norm is continuous with respect to the topology of uniform convergence. Since $\|\sin x\|_{\infty}=1$ and every non-constant polynomial $p(x)$ satisfies $\|p(x)\|_{\infty}=\infty$, it follows immediately that $\sin x$ admits no uniform approximation by polynomials on $\mathbb R$.

For $e^x$ the same argument applies after restricting the domain to $(-\infty,0]$, since any uniform approximation on $\mathbb R$ will also restrict to a uniform approximation on $(-\infty,0]$.

Answer (score 2):

For $e^{x}$ simply use the fact that it remains bounded as $x \to -\infty$ whereas the absolute value of a polynomial tends to $\infty$.

For the first function your answer is correct.